# Pricing for Plan "Production Standard 1X"

Tags: heroku, pricing

I've got a question regarding your Plan "Production Standard 1X"

It says that the price is "$25 and up per month" on top of the pricing page, but it says "(max of $25 per month)" in the dyno section. What does that exactly mean?

Do I pay $25 fix price per month? Less? What are dyno hours if the dyno is up and running all the time?

Does it account for concurrent users? Does the price increase with concurrent users?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Although there are some Salesforce employees who are members/users of this site, SFSE is not part of Salesforce nor is it connected to Salesforce in any official capacity.

Comment: The question is about HEROKU pricing ... I was sent over from heroku.com for questions if I'm not a paying customer yet

Comment: HEROKU is owned by Salesforce. SFSE is also not part of Heroku nor is it connected to Heroku in any official capacity. Your first line [emphasis added], "I've got a question regarding **your** Plan..." makes it sound like you think this is a Heroku/Salesforce site. A lot of people post questions (and complaints) thinking that this site has some official connection.